# Dynamics of electrons on a sphere

Tags: reference-request, mg.metric-geometry, classical-mechanics

Suppose one place $n$ electrons closely surrounding the north pole of a sphere, forming
a perfect planar regular $n$-gon:

---

[image]

---

> ***Q1***.
>   What will happen if the electrons repel one another via Coulomb's law, but are
>   confined to the surface?
>   Will they maintain a planar regular $n$-gon configuration?
>   With damping will they settle on the equator?

I believe the answer to the latter two questions is *Yes*, but I did not attempt
a formal proof. Here is my primary interest:

> ***Q2***.
>   Suppose small random errors are introduced so that the initial configuration
>   is not an exact planar regular $n$-gon.
>   Will the electrons on average head toward the expected minimum energy configuration?

For $n{=}7$ illustrated above, that min configuration is conjectured to be an equatorial
regular pentagon with electrons occupying the two poles.
Perhaps especially with larger $n$,
there are many local minima rendering it unlikely to settle in the min-energy configuration?

Comment: The answer to **Q1** must be Yes, because the differential equation
has a unique solution so it must retain the initial symmetry. 
For **Q2** the particles must approach a stable local minimum,
but in general they don't have to find a global minimum, and
the probability of success might depend also on the strength of
the damping.  (Is a regular $n$-gon on the equator locally stable
once $n>3$?)

Comment: @NoamD.Elkies: Nice question on stability of equatorial $n$-gons. Thanks!

Comment: I did a Matlab computation which showed that for $n>4$ the regular $n$-gon on the equator is locally unstable.
m=20;

f3=zeros(1,m);

for n=2:m

    ind=(0:n-1)*2*pi/n;

    x=[cos(ind);sin(ind);zeros(1,n)];

    eps=10^(-4);

    y=[cos(eps);0;sin(eps)];

    %force

    F=zeros(3,1);

    for i=2:n

       xi=x(:,i);

       F=F+(y-xi)/norm(y-xi)^3; 

    end

    %projection

    F=F-(F'*y)*y;

    f3(n)=F(3)/eps;

end

f3

Comment: @NoamD.Elkies: *The answer to Q1 must be Yes, because the differential equation has a unique solution so it must retain the initial symmetry.* I don't think this really constitutes a proof, since there are counterexamples such as the famous Norton's dome: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Norton%27s_dome . The problem is basically that solutions to the equations of motion in Newtonian mechanics may be nonunique, i.e., Newtonian mechanics is not actually deterministic in all cases.

Comment: This seems closely analogous to packing of hard spheres, where it is known that random packing is always worse than the optimal packing. So I think it's very unlikely that such a system achieves the global minimum in all cases.

Comment: @BenCrowell non-unique solutions can happen but only when the system starts at a singularity or reaches a singularity. Here the electrons start in different (albeit close) positions, and they can never crash into each other because the exert repulsive forces on each other that blow up as $r \to 0$.

Comment: @NoamD.Elkies: *non-unique solutions can happen but only when the system starts at a singularity or reaches a singularity* I don't think this is true, since Norton's dome would seem to be a counterexample. It certainly doesn't have any singularity of the particular type you describe. Or did you have in mind some definition of singularity more general than the example you gave? If so, what is it -- a singularity in what function? The indeterminacy of Norton's dome is usually described not as an issue involving a singularity but as one involving a lack of Lipschitz continuity.